# What is the cause of the Coriolis force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, coriolis-effect

What is the cause of [Coriolis force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coriolis_force)? Will a bead fixed on the spoke of a rotating wheel experience a Coriolis force?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if the bead moves radially along the spoke it will experience a Coriolis force. If the bead is fixed in position on the spoke it will only experience a centrifugal force.

Place yourself in the frame of the rotating wheel. In this frame of reference there is a centrifugal force on the bead, causing it to accelerate radially outwards. Because of this radial motion there is also a Coriolis force pushing it sideways into the rotating spoke. The origin of both these fictitious forces is the bead's tendency to move in a straight line, ie its inertia.

The Coriolis force is opposed by the normal reaction of the spoke. If the bead did not move, it would not experience any sideways Coriolis force, nor any tangential reaction force from the spoke.

Both of these fictitious forces are invoked in order to explain the motion of an object which is not constrained by any real forces, from the point of view of an observer rotating with the wheel. From the point of view of the ground the object moves in a straight line. From the point of view of an observer on the wheel the object moves outward and sideways (opposite to the direction of rotation). If the object (the bead) is constrained to move on the rotating rod, then it only moves outwards. The Coriolis force is balanced by the normal reaction from the spoke, so the bead does not move sideways relative to the spoke.

Answer (score 0):

It will. The normal reaction due to the spoke on the bead will provide the required force. However, the bead is constrained to stay on the spoke, and can only slide up or down.

A Coriolis force is needed to provide the Coriolis acceleration, which is a natural consequence of looking at motion in a rotating frame of reference with changing *radial* velocity.